# VirtualBox shared folders error

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint, shared-folders, guest-additions

I want to setup a shared folder on Windows 10 host and Linux Mint guest to transfer files on VirtualBox. But when I Go to `Devices/ Guest Additions`, this error pops up. Anyone has any idea what is happening?

[image]

Comment: Wild guess: put the iso in a location without spaces - or any other special characters - in its path.